# Is there any standardized, cross-platform, way to represent relative file paths?

Tags: linux, windows, url, filesystems, standards

I am working on a tool to handle dependency resolution on the JVM. I expect users to give me maven coordinates in the form of [package urls](https://github.com/package-url/purl-spec) and I output a list of file paths containing their dependencies.

```
jresolve pkg:maven/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind@2.15.2
```

```
/Users/emccue/.jresolve/cache/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.15.2/jackson-annotations-2.15.2.jar:/Users/emccue/.jresolve/cache/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.15.2/jackson-core-2.15.2.jar:/Users/emccue/.jresolve/cache/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.15.2/jackson-databind-2.15.2.jar
```

Because this is intended to be used on a `--class-path`, I also support providing paths on the filesystem, which will be forwarded as-is onto the generated path.

```
jresolve some/path
```

```
some/path
```

My problem is that I really *want* to make people specify file paths with `file:///`, because that is an actual url and a standardized format.

```
jresolve file:///some/path
```

```
/some/path
```

And a really neat property is that I can turn that into an OS-specific path easily.

```
\some\path
```

But paths specified in that way are absolute paths by every spec I found. Hence the leading forward slash.

So my question is: Is there any format which has a standard or de-facto standard which can represent a relative file path in an os-agnostic way?

Comment: RFC 3986 defines *relative* references: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-26

Comment: _"i really want to make people specify file paths with `file:///` ..."_ — sorry, I don't understand this, as this is by definition an absolute path; OS-agnostic relative file paths literally _are_ in the form `some/path` (forgive me if I've misunderstood the question, but fwiw, absolute `file:///` refs generally have been A Bad Thing imho, because people don't like to and/or can't specify things relative to their system root directory for reasons beyond their control)